# How do I nuke RubyGems and start again from scratch?

Tags: macos, rubygems

I've been trying to update cocoapods on my laptop this evening and I'm getting a weird RubyGems error...

With the following command...

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

I got the following error.

> ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'cocoapods' (>= 0), here is why:
>             Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: tlsv1 alert protocol version (https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)

Not sure where to go from here. This used to work (two weeks ago) and the only reference I found online was from 4 years ago.

I tried updating gems `gem update --system` but it told me I'm on the latest version.

I can list gems and uninstall them. I just can't install them?

Oh man. I managed to get it to update with `sudo` and now with...

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

I get the error...

> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
>       Operation not permitted - /usr/bin/xcodeproj

No idea what that means?!

Oh god! OK, so I followed the advice here... https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3692

And `pod init` worked. But when I restarted terminal it now says `pod: command not found`.

How do I nuke ruby gems and start again?